# IE not wrapping around floating div but FF is

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have my webpage working perfectly in Firefox. But in IE it doesnt wrap properly.

the parents div for both columns is:

```
.underbars
{
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top: 140px;
    position: absolute;    
}
```

In this div there are 2 divs, one is floating and the other should sit directly to the right of the floating div, The reason the second div is not floating is because I want it to take up the left over space. in IE the second div sits directly under the first div.

floating div: (should be on left hand side)

```
.cabinetpane
{

    border-right: 1px solid #c1c0c1;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-right-color: #c1c0c1;
    border-bottom-color: #c1c0c1;    
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #3B4F65;
}
```

Wrapping div (should be directly to the right and take up all available space)

```
<div> </div> //No css for this one
```

Comment: Which IE version are you dealing with?

Comment: Can we have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: sure. its http://www.aussiehaulage.com.au/  And im dealing with IE9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution i could come up with is to have a div that has the single purpose of aligning things (it is only for structure, no color / borders are displayed).

Here is the box model: 
[image]

That div im talking about is the one you want to "take up the left over space" aka the orange box. 
Inside that div a style is applied that dictates, the div will have a margin-left (this margin should be as wide as the float-left column you had) so that when another div is placed inside and given width:100%, in this case the blue div (i gave it 90 because of padding and borders etc. you will need to fiddle around with this based on what borders/margins/padding you have) that blue div will always occupy the rest of the space.

To sum it up by colour:

- Black = your left column div that is a fixed with
- Orange = div used for structure (should not have borders / background etc.)
- Greed = metaphorical representation of the left-margin used on the orange div
- blue = the div that fills the space on the right.

P.S. I tested this in IE8

you can find all the css/html [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lyubent/TNZ8c/) and i recomend using [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/) every time you are posting a CSS/js/HTML related issue a picture paints 1000 words.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to is what Lyuben Todorov said, something like this would work:

```
<style>
.col1 { width:250px; float:left }
</style>

<div class="col1">
I'm 250
</div>
<div class="col2">
I'm as long as you want me to be, just don't define me! 
</div>
```

... if that's what I think you're talking about now

Comment: he wants 2 columns where one column is a fixed size and the other column is taking up the rest of the space:
`250px` | `rest of space`

Comment: I forgot to mention I want the first div to take up the amount of space required fro the dynamic text